# JaxRS response general header

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-8

is there any way to set general header on response of all api paths in JaxRS ?
for example i have a api like this :

```
@Path("/api/v1")
public class JaxRsConfig extends Application {
}
```

and

```
@Path("/voucher")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Voucher {
    
    @POST
    public Response add(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response get(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response list(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }
}
```

and this:

```
@Path("/invoice")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Invoice {

    @POST
    public Response add(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response get(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response list(...) {
        return Response.ok().header("API_EXPIRE_DATE","2025/05/12").build();
    }
}
```

I always have to put this header in the response .
JaxRs has any mechanism to set this header generally ?
**Note:** I use JavaEE-8 on Liberty Application Server

Comment: ContainerResponseFilter

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `WriterInterceptor` to add this header.
Some good examples explained here: https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter12/reader_and_writer_interceptors.html